# Why cant i get my advanced supply drop?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

I reached lol 30 and the game says I won an advanced supply drop but it didn't pop up and I can't open it

Comment: Hello. The [tag:glitch] tag is actually the name of a game. Instead of that tag, you'll want to use the proper tag for your game. I believe you're likely talking about cod: aw, but if not, you should edit and choose the right tag.